# Connect saparate query into one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i'm trying to do a query which present my data in no typical way. The easiest way to explain is example so:

header:

```
    SELECT
    '010' header,
    '54' as number1,
    'MAC' sender
    from dual
```

---

```
table1

select
phonenumber,
clientid
from table1


output: 
 phonenumer   clientid
   54234         3
   4234          2
   41211         5
```

---

table2

```
select
    productname,
    productid
    from table2

output: 
 productname productid
   Apple       9
   TV          2
```

table1, table2 and header are not connected. As output I will excpect:

```
010   54  MAC    <- from header
54234 3          <- from query1
      Apple 9    <- from query2
010   54  MAC
4234  2
      TV  2
```

and so on.

How to handle with what? I was trying to use cross join,union. Could u give my some hints ?

Maybe it's imposible to do by using SQL? Should I create a procedure/function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the rows using `union all`.  Then you can interleave the values using `row_number()` or `rownum` and order them using `order by`:

```
select header, number1, sender
from ((select header, number1, sender, 1 as priority, NULL as rn
       from header
      ) union all
      (select phonenumber, clientid, NULL, 2, rownum as rn
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select NULL, productname, productid, 2, rownum as rn
       from table2
      )
     ) t
order by priority, rn, header nulls last;
```

Answer (score 1):

just suggest using `CROSS JOIN` if you want to output some data in different table here the example code :

```
SELECT TITLE, NUMBER_THEATER, PRICE    
FROM FILM, THEATER;
```

so the output will be the data inside

`TITLE`  , `Number_THEATER` and `PRICE`

note : `FILM` and `THEATER` are different table, hope this useful :)